# iOS local notifations on new pictures in gallery

Tags: ios, push-notification, image-gallery

I would like to show a badge on my app icon when new pictures are taken on the phone stock camera.
How can I register for this event? If not possible , is there a way to tell when iCloud of the user added new photos and get notify the user to open the application?
If not can I schedule an event to the user (lets say every hour) and run some code to check if pictures were added to the gallery - if so display a badge so the user will open my app?